# How to undo/redo using my mx mouse's thumb button

Tags: shortcut, linux, mouse

How can I have the undo/redo function using my [MX Mouse thumb buttons](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_buttons#Thumb_Buttons_-_forward_and_back), similar as I'm  using them in Firefox (forward/backward)